# custom session attribute in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I create a custom session attribute to perform the following:

**e.g: Turn:**

```
public int invoicingAddressId
{
   get    {  return int.Parse(Session["invoicingAddressId"].ToString());  }
   set    {  Session["invoicingAddressId"] = value;  }
}
```

**Into:**

```
[session()]
public int invoicingAddressId {get;set;}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: As an aside traditionally in C# we use Pascal case for properties and classes (therefore also attributes) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: What if `Session["invoicingAddressId"]` is `null` ?

Comment: What is the motivation behind this?

Comment: Consider: `class A { [Session()]Id{get;set;} } class B { [Session()]Id{get;set;} }` and `var a = new A(){Id=1}; var b = new B(){Id=2}; var aId = a.Id;` What is the value of `aId` ?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

That's not really how attributes work.  At least not without an AoP framework of some sort.

As some others have pointed out, even if it could work, there are way too many edge cases to make this reliable.. null values, exceptions, etc...